# Linkage of Classes and Class members

Tags: c++, object, header-files, linkage

Here are the definitions I know for external and internal linkage.

**Having internal linkage** : can be used within a translation unit.

**Having external linkage** : existing beyond a particular translation unit, being accessible through the whole program.

*Here is an example :*

Say I have a headers file called A.h where I declare class members and members methods (constructor, destructor...). In a cpp file called A.cpp I define those methods.

In a main.cpp file where I included my headers file, I create an object a of type A with the constructor of the class A.

Now say I declared A's class members as private or protected, I can't access them through my main.cpp file. If I declare them as public I can.

**Here is my question** : does it make sense to say that A's class members have internal linkage when I declare them as private or protected?

I am very confused with what linkage actually represents, and when talking about internal or external linkage is possible.

Comment: This may help: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration

Comment: @NicolBolas 
`class A {
    protected : 
        int name;
};`

name is what I would call an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

> Now say I declared A's class members as private or protected, I can't access them through my main.cpp file.

Yes, you can. Simply take one of those definitions from `A.cpp` and move them over to `main.cpp`. That definition will be able to access `A`'s private members. That's perfectly legal and valid C++.

Access controls (public/private/etc) determine which code can name the members of that class. They do not control *where* those members get defined. That is, access controls can hide names based on the specific context of the code where those names appear, not the file in which the name appears.

Linkage (in part) controls the visibility of names across *the entire program*, relative to a specific translation unit (aka: source file) in which that name was declared/defined. Linkage very much cares which files a name appears in, relative to where that name was declared/defined.

That being said, members of a type don't have linkage at all. You could consider them to have the same linkage as the type itself. Linkage applies to namespace/globally scoped declarations and definitions, not to class members.